# Convergence or diverge of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n} - e^{-n^2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I was studying sequences and series from a book when I ran into the following problem. The text before the problem indicated that I should be using Ratio test or Root test to solve it, however root test didn't seem to fit well and ratio test was inconclusive (resulted in a ratio of $1$)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n} - e^{-n^2}\right)$$

Any hints or actual answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance 
Also please comment as to why it is off-topic before voting to close it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct, in this case the ratio test or the root test is inconclusive.

Hint. Note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{n} - e^{-n^2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-n^2}$$
Now recall that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent and 
$$0\leq \sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-n^2}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n}=\frac{1}{e-1}.$$
What may we conclude?